# MVC Entity Framework INDEX page format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a  new MVC Entity Framework Application. When it created the Index List  page - it looks like the  Headers are ran together. Have  small size fields and the field names are longer than the fields.  How to format that page to make Header  spaced out so it doesn't all run together.

Could not post a pic  - something like this - sorry the  data line  ran together on the past.

RE NUMINT RE NAME

1      I   SHAWN NEWT

```
@model IEnumerable<MTSapp.Models.mts_rename> 
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; } 
<h2>Index</h2> 
<p> @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") </p> 


<table> 
    <tr> 
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.A_RENO) </th> 
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.A_INACT) </th> 
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.A_NAME) </th> 
        <th></th> 
    </tr>           
    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    { 
        <tr> 
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A_RENO) </td> 
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A_INACT) </td> 
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A_NAME) </td> 
        </tr> 
    } 
</table>
```

Comment: You need to check your CSS. VS has gone to Bootstrap layouts in recent versions, so first thing would be to check if that package is installed. Check your NUGET packages to see if bootstrap is installed. If it's not, you need to install it or inspect the CSS you are using with Chrome tools or something else.

Comment: Post your view code.

Comment: Using Internet Explorer - that is what's  supported in out  shop currently -I did not have  Bootstrap CSS  instll or at least it  said INSTALL when I went to the NUGET page - will install & do some reading on CSS. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Chris Pratt  not sure how to add the code - know stupid right - when I tried to paste in it said it was too long.  Must have put it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the page using a table or some type of grid? You may need to apply some CSS rules to get the page nicely formatted. Does the page have any CSS styling yet?

Comment: The data is coming from a SQL Server database - simple table with 3 columns -  think it has table has <tr>  in the code   - am looking into the CCS styling - guess I thought that was automatic simple things can wreck your day - very new to this

Comment: Please try to post some code for reference, it is pretty difficult to offer any solutions based on your description without any reference. There is a large number of possible problems that could be occurring to cause this your table to not display properly.

Comment: @model IEnumerable<MTSapp.Models.mts_rename>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

Comment: <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.A_RENO)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.A_INACT)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.A_NAME)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

Comment: Tis is BAD - just don't know any other way to include the code
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A_RENO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A_INACT)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A_NAME)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

Comment: I edited your original post with the code formatted nicely. When you create a new post, there should be an option in the WSIWYG editor for adding code. This [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) gives a nice explanation of how to post code. But unfortunately, what you posted doesn't really reveal why you are having your problem. If your table isn't wide enough, make sure you are setting the width to as wide as you can make it.

Comment: THank you for doing that - I will take a look -  thinking it's the CSS styling

Comment: finally got the CSS working for my index sheet - not Majic will definitely be a learning curve for CSS styling -  where are the good ol days of drag & drop :)